# Cron job needs to be modified after it has started running

Tags: cron

I have a cron job that has already started running a script. I made changes to this script  while the job was running.

Is it true that the cron job will continue running the old script rather than the new script?
If so, what can be the negative consequences of stopping the currently running cron job and starting it again so that it runs a new script?

P.S. I am not attaching the script just because the question is theoretical. But is it is crucial for the script to be attached please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: The harm in interrupting the script is entirely related to what the script is doing and how it handles being interrupted. That part of the question is not really a cron question.

Comment: The question of what your script will do if its edited during execution depends on what kind of script it is. My understanding is, for example, python scripts don't update based on edits, but a bash script could in certain circumstances.

Comment: So you should likely separate this into two questions and provide more information for each.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The script is a bash script. It makes a postgresql base backup. The old script was the following:           
FILE=$PGDBBACKUPDIR/$db.dump
pg_dump -h $MASTER_IP -U postgres -c -b $db > $FILE                                         In the new one I added "-Fc" to change the format of the backup file to custom format (the custom format also compresses the file, as I understand.                                           
 FILE=$PGDBBACKUPDIR/$db.dump
 pg_dump -Fc -h $MASTER_IP -U postgres -c -b $db > $FILE

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.